# What is the differences between code injection and sub-classing in Java

Tags: code-injection, subclassing, javassist

I was reading about code-injection at run-time and there are many tools/APIs available like Javassist, GluonJ and AspectJ which provide features to inject code. However, I did not understand purpose for injecting code at run-time while we can do override behaviors by sub-classing in Java. With Javassist and GluonJ, I can create classes at run-time but why does anyone do that, in the first place? Can anyone please help me to understand the difference and purpose of code injection ?

Answer (score 0):

Code injection is usually used into `application that are used to modify/check/trace other software.` In Java we usually reffer to this kind of library as `Bytecode modification libraries` so if you look on the internet you will probably find more information under this name.

Here I listed a couple of examples of big and famous projects that I now are using Bytecode modification into their cores:

1. [Evosuite](http://www.evosuite.org/): this project takes an application in input and generates unit test for it. Code injection is used to explore the desired project and dependencies and traceability
2. [JaCoCO](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/): this project is a tool for Java project. It is supposed to be attached to your application and once you run your JUnit tests it is going to generate a report on the coverage achieved. Obviously here code injection is necessary to trace every method call made during test execution.